# 'cannot resolve file or directory "react"', with react-rails gem and rubymine

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, rubymine, react-rails

I am using `react-rails` gem and `Rubymine`.  After `rails g react:install`, my `application.js` file looks like this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require react
//= require react_ujs
//= require components
//= require_tree .
```

Everything except `//= require react` is recognised.  Rubymine tells me `Cannot resolve file or directory "react".`

When I look at my `Rails.application.config.assets.paths`, I see my react gem path and I can find `react_ujs.js.erb` there, but no `react.js*` file.  Is this some kind of bug with the `react-rails` gem?

What would be the proper way of fixing this?

EDIT: According to the `react-rails` documentation section on [react builds](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails/blob/master/README.md#reactjs-builds), the right react build can be selected by assigning the environment symbol in the appropriate environment file.  Doing so still doesn't resolve the `Rubymine` warning, but copying the `react.js` file into one of the assets path location does.  It seems like something `react-rails` doesn't do very well with `Rubymine`.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://ttrmw.co.uk/code/rails_and_react_with_npm_modules.html) can help.